# Dropdown to show or hide div content is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why this script wont work:

```
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="divname1"> Loan Protection Insurance</option>
  <option value="divname2"> GAP or Cash Assist Insurance</option>
  <option value="divname3"> Home Insurance</option>
  <option value="divname4"> Landlords Insurance</option>
  <option value="divname5"> Car Insurance</option>
</select>

<div id="divname1" style="display: block">Test 1</div>
<div id="divname2">Test 2</div>
<div id="divname3">Test 3</div>
<div id="divname4">Test 4</div>
<div id="divname5">Test 5</div>

document.getElementById('id-of-select').onchange = function() {
    var i = 1;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("divname" + i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById("divname" + ++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};

div {
display: none;   
}
```

Here is the code
http://jsfiddle.net/2ukyA/7/

However i can get this code working
http://jsfiddle.net/2ukyA/

But i want to have more than one of these on a page so i need something that isn't based on just numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding all divs manually, you could just hide the `<div>` related to the previously selected value. You could store an associative array (like a map) in which you had, for a given `<select>` id, the last selected value, or even `<div>` id. In the `onchange` event handler, just hide the `<div>` with the id in the map, and show the new one.

Notice you'll still need to have an association (implicit if they're the same, or explicit if you store it in an array) between the `<option>` and the `<div>` id.

See an example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ukyA/19/).

In this example, there is a multidimensional associative array (sort of a map of maps) that stores the `<option>`s for each `<select>`. Each `<option>` is also associated to the `<div>` id it shows when selected. This same array is used to store the previously selected value for the array (in the entry `previousValue`).

Notice the definition of the associative array is done statically in javacsript, but it could be dynamically retrieved off an external JSON file, or an AJAX request. The `<select>` elements could also be dynamically built, but you'd need a little bit more information (i.e. option descriptions).

Javascript:

```
var selectDivOptions= 
    {select1:  
     { 
        option11: 'div11',
        option12: 'div12',
        option13: 'div13'
     }, 
     select2:  { 
         option21: 'div21',
         option22: 'div22',
         option23: 'div23'
     } 
    };

for (var key in selectDivOptions){
    var element = document.getElementById(key);
    element.onchange = selectChange;
}

function selectChange(){
    // Hide the div pointed by the previous value
    var previousValue = selectDivOptions[this.id]['previousValue'];
    if (previousValue){
        document.getElementById(previousValue).style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Show the div
    var divToShow = selectDivOptions[this.id][this.value];
    if (divToShow){
        document.getElementById(divToShow).style.display='block';
    }
    // Store the current value as the previous value
    selectDivOptions[this.id]['previousValue'] = divToShow;
}
```

HTML

```
<select name="options" id="select1">
  <option value="option11"> Option 11</option>
  <option value="option12"> Option 12</option>
  <option value="option13"> Option 13</option>
</select>

<div id="div11">Div 11</div>
<div id="div12">Div 12</div> 
<div id="div13">Div 13</div> 

<br />
<select name="options2" id="select2">
  <option value="option21"> Option 21</option>
  <option value="option22"> Option 22</option>
  <option value="option23"> Option 23</option>
</select>
<div id="div21">Div 21</div>
<div id="div22">Div 22</div> 
<div id="div23">Div 23</div>
```

Comment: The first dropdown on the jsfiddle doesnt seem to do anything for me, the 2nd one works fine?

Comment: Actually, it was quite a dumb error. The `selectChange` function was receiving `select2` all of the time. It doesn't even need a parameter, you can reference the `<select>` with `this` inside the function. See updated answer, and updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ukyA/19/).